# Print text into console at specific position

Tags: python, bash

I want to print text at specific postion in bash terminal using python.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: "`bash`" and "terminal" are two entirely separate things.

Comment: Your answer assumes you are asking about an ANSI-compatible terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function can print in any position in terminal (linux).

```py
import sys

# https://github.com/setnicka/ulozto-downloader/blob/2f92a3d91aa754f6fff3c31f43c5a75a60a8273e/uldlib/utils.py#L5
def _print(text, x=0, y=0):
    sys.stdout.write("\033[{};{}H".format(y, x))
    sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: On my Mac Terminal it reset the prompt to the printed position.

Comment: The function is for linux terminal